# Slices in MS Expression Design have wrong dimensions

Tags: tools, export, microsoft-expression

I'm trying to do some basic design in Microsoft Expression Design 4 (this is the best design tool I have available to me; suggestions welcome), and I'm trying to export slices by selecting a bunch of objects and using the right-click context menu to create a slice from the selection.  Slices created like this always have 2px of transparency at the extremes of the vertical axis.  How do I get my slices to have the exact dimensions of the selections used to create them?

Comment: I would suggest using a different tool. GIMP is a great open-source, free image editing tool. Otherwise, I'm not familiar enough with this software to be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was an element in my design that was causing the slice to seem to be wrong.  I had a vertical stroke, 6 pixels wide, with a horizontal gradient fill.  The stroke itself was only 77 pixels long, but it was causing the slices to be 82 pixels high.  I don't know why, but when I resized this stroke to 74 pixels, the slice dimensions were correct.

I discovered this by moving the slice bounds around and seeing the dimensions change as certain elements moved out of the bounds.